# How do I install a CentOS 5.5 in Xenserver?

Tags: linux, virtualization, installation, xenserver

When I try to install CentOS 5.5 in a new VM, I get an error that the installer is unable to retrieve stage2.img.  I have verified the URL and I am able to download this file from a web browser.

I suspect it is a networking/routing issue, but I can't figure out what is wrong.  This is a new install of XenServer 5.6 on a new server.

This server is remote, so I don't have physical access to the box - only ssh access.

Can anyone give me some tips on what might be wrong here?  Do I need to do something special to get a net install to work?

For what it's worth, I see the same error trying to install Debian Woody using a similar process.

[Console Screenshot http://img.skitch.com/20100608-ki5wnghn57w4cwies4txs2akwc.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100608-ki5wnghn57w4cwies4txs2akwc.png)

[Update] On the host, here is the output of ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:B9:66:F4:1B  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:550110 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:87730 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:175102636 (166.9 MiB)  TX bytes:46959244 (44.7 MiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e6000000-e6012800 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:B9:66:F4:1D  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Interrupt:19 Memory:e8000000-e8012800 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:B9:66:EC:44  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Interrupt:18 Memory:ea000000-ea012800 

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:B9:66:EC:46  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:ec000000-ec012800 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:35166 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35166 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:74186349 (70.7 MiB)  TX bytes:74186349 (70.7 MiB)

xenbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:B9:66:F4:1B  
          inet addr:38.101.26.97  Bcast:38.101.26.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:511631 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:63220 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:159956363 (152.5 MiB)  TX bytes:44989078 (42.9 MiB)

xenbr1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:B9:66:F4:1D  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

xenbr2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:B9:66:EC:44  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

xenbr3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:B9:66:EC:46  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Were you guided through the network setup before this screen appeared? Either the virtual network card isn't being detected, or more likely, Xen isn't running DHCP so you have to manually configure the IP/DNS/Gateway settings before you can complete the netinstall.

Comment: Yes.  The screen before this one asks for network information.  I chose the DHCP as the option and it appeared to acquire an IP address successfully via DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your path to the server images. It's showing a double back slash before the "images" directory in the URL (//images)

Be careful entering the remote server info. You don't need to put a slash at the end of the top line nor the start of the bottom one - the application will do it for you.

Just pay attention to the URL and re-edit it until it shows up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I did not understand how networking in XenServer works.  The networks to the virtual machines are bridged to the NIC on the machine.  Therefore each VM needs a dedicated IP address.  Once I assigned another IP address from my provider, I was able to configure the VM with that IP address manually and it worked like a charm.